# Conditioning with multiple Cursors

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 5 cursors and i'm trying to make a conditioning structure that opens and process the relevant cursor, based on user input. The function is supposed to collect the results in a single string. The code apparently has errors and i cannot for the life of me figure out where i've gone wrong. Thank you good sirs for your help!

```
create or replace function listnation1(region_name in varchar2)
return varchar2
IS
DECLARE
    CURSOR africaCursor IS 
    SELECT n_name
    FROM nation
    where n_regionkey = 0;

    CURSOR americaCursor IS 
    SELECT n_name
    FROM nation
    where n_regionkey = 1;

    CURSOR asiaCursor IS 
    SELECT n_name
    FROM nation
    where n_regionkey = 2;

    CURSOR europeCursor IS 
    SELECT n_name
    FROM nation
    where n_regionkey = 3;

    CURSOR midEastCursor IS 
    SELECT n_name
    FROM nation
    where n_regionkey = 4;

    aString varchar2 := "";

BEGIN
    IF region_name = "Africa" THEN
        aString := "0   ";
        FOR i in africaCursor LOOP
            CONCAT(aString, str(i.n_name));
            CONCAT(aString, ", ");
        END LOOP;

    ELSIF region_name = "America" THEN LOOP
        aString := "1   ";
        FOR i in americaCursor LOOP
            CONCAT(aString, str(i.n_name));
            CONCAT(aString, ", ");
        END LOOP;

    ELSIF region_name = "Asia" THEN LOOP
        aString := "2   ";
        FOR i in asiaCursor LOOP
            CONCAT(aString, str(i.n_name));
            CONCAT(aString, ", ");
        END LOOP;

    ELSIF region_name = "Europe" THEN LOOP
        aString := "3   ";
        FOR i in europeCursor LOOP
            CONCAT(aString, str(i.n_name));
            CONCAT(aString, ", ");
        END LOOP;

    ELSIF region_name = "Middle East" THEN LOOP
        aString := "4   ";
        FOR i in midEastCursor LOOP
            CONCAT(aString, str(i.n_name));
            CONCAT(aString, ", ");
        END LOOP;
    END IF;

    return aString;
END listnation1;
/
```

Comment: Quoted literals use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson hi! thanks for your reply! i tried changing all the double quotes to single quotes but theres still a compile error somehow

Comment: Those 5 cursors is just an overkill. You could simply do it using SQL, or if absolutely necessary in PL/SQL then one single cursor FOR LOOP is enough.

Comment: Regarding syntax errors, you have a stray `DECLARE` at the top and some extra `LOOP` keywords, `aString varchar2` needs a size and `str` doesn't seem to be declared although it could be a function in your schema. Also the `CONCAT` calls won't work because it's a function so the result needs to be assigned to something e.g. `x := concat('abc', 'def');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 cursors solution is most probably the worst you could have written. Basically, you don't need cursors at all - `LISTAGG` can do it in a single query. Here's how:

```
create or replace function listnation1 (par_region_name in varchar2)
  return varchar2 
is
  retval varchar2(4000);
begin
  select listagg(n.n_name, ',') within group (order by n.n_name)
    into retval
    from nation n
    where n.n_regionkey = case when par_region_name = 'Africa'      then 0
                               when par_region_name = 'America'     then 1
                               when par_region_name = 'Asia'        then 2
                               when par_region_name = 'Europe'      then 3
                               when par_region_name = 'Middle East' then 4
                          end;
  return retval;
end;
/
```

---

If it must be cursor-related solution, why not cursor FOR loop?

```
create or replace function listnation1 (par_region_name in varchar2)
  return varchar2 
is
  retval varchar2(4000);
begin
  for cur_r in 
   (select n.n_name
    from nation n
    where n.n_regionkey = case when par_region_name = 'Africa'      then 0
                               when par_region_name = 'America'     then 1
                               when par_region_name = 'Asia'        then 2
                               when par_region_name = 'Europe'      then 3
                               when par_region_name = 'Middle East' then 4
                          end
   ) 
  loop
    retval := retval || cur_r.n_name ||',';
  end loop;    

  return rtrim(retval, ',');
end;
/
```

Comment: hi! thank you for your help! it seems that my understanding of plsql is still severely lacking hahaha i'll try out the cursor for loop!

Comment: Don't. Use the first option, will be way faster for larger data sets.

Comment: @Littlefoot is correct, do not use a loop. If you want to write good SQL, you have to think about the issue in terms of SETs of items not individual items. While loop structures are sometimes necessary it is rarely needed. (Virtually always the output result require not data collection (select). Consider using a loop construct only as an extreme last resort.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the return value of the concat function. It should be something like

```
aString := CONCAT(aString, ', ');
```

You can also write

```
aString := aString || i.n_name || ', ';
```

Note also that the string delimiter is a single quote. Double quotes are used to escape table or column names in Oracle.

In SQL you get the best performance with SELECT commands. Avoid loops and cursors if possible.

Comment: `SET` is not an Oracle syntax.

Comment: You are right. I looked up "Oracle SET" and jumped into the docs.oracle.com site but didn't see it was the MySQL Reference Manual.

Comment: It happens with me too sometimes :)